# How to add localStorage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, e-commerce, shopping-cart

How do I add a localStorage for my code?
I'm just a beginner programmer so I don't really know that much about javascript. I've watched other youtube videos but it didn't help me with my code.

```
// cart 

let cartIcon = document.querySelector("#cart-icon");
let cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
let closeCart = document.querySelector("#close-cart");
//open cart
cartIcon.onclick = () => {
    cart.classList.add('active');
};
//close cart
closeCart.onclick = () => {
    cart.classList.remove('active');
};

// Cart Working JS

if (document.readyState == 'loading'){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
}else{
    ready();
}

//making function

function ready() {
    //remove items from cart
    var removeCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-cart');
    console.log(removeCartButtons);
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartButtons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
    }
    // quantity changes
    var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity');
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
        var input = quantityInputs[i];
        input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
    }
    // add to cart
    var addCart = document.getElementsByClassName('add-cart');
    for (var i = 0; i < addCart.length; i++) {
    var button = addCart[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', addCartClicked);
    }
    //buy button work
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn-check-out')[0].addEventListener('click', buyButtonClicked);
}
// buy button
function buyButtonClicked(){
    alert('Your Order has been placed');
    var cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
    while (cartContent.hasChildNodes()){
        cartContent.removeChild(cartContent.firstChild);
    }
    updatetotal();
}

//remove items from cart
function removeCartItem(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.remove();
    updatetotal();
}

//quantity changes
function quantityChanged(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
        input.value = 1;
    }
    updatetotal();
}

//add cart
function addCartClicked(event) {
    var button = event.target;
    var shopProducts = button.parentElement;
    var title = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-title')[0].innerText;
    var price = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-price')[0].innerText;
    var productImg = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image")[0].src;
    addProductToCart(title, price, productImg);
    updatetotal();
}
function addProductToCart(title, price, productImg){
    var cartShopBox = document.createElement('div');
    cartShopBox.classList.add('cart-box');
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
    var cartItemsNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-product-title');
    for (var i = 0; i < cartItemsNames.length; i++) {
        if (cartItemsNames[i].innerText == title) {
        alert("Item already added to cart");  // needs changes since it can't read the title
        return;
        }
    }
var cartBoxContent = `
                    <img src="${productImg}" alt="" class="cart-img">
                    <div class="detail-box">
                        <div class="cart-product-title">${title}</div>
                        <div class="cart-price">${price}</div>
                        <input type="number" value="1" class="cart-quantity">
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash remove-cart" ></i>`;

cartShopBox.innerHTML = cartBoxContent;
cartItems.append(cartShopBox);
cartShopBox.getElementsByClassName('remove-cart')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
cartShopBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
}

//update total
function updatetotal() {
    var cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-content')[0];
    var cartBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-box');
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cartBoxes.length; i++) {
        var cartBox = cartBoxes[i];
        var priceElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0];
        var quantityElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity')[0];
        var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace("$", ""));
        var quantity = quantityElement.value;
        total = total + price * quantity;
    }
        // if price contain some cents value
        total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;

        document.getElementsByClassName('total-price')[0].innerText = "$" + total;
}
```

Comment: First google search result: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage - youtube is fine, but it's not the only resource. Learn to use the site I link to. VERY helpful and everyone here consults it often

Answer (score 1):

To add some data to local storage you need to:

```
localStorage.setItem("fruit", "apple");
```

If you want to retrieve data from local storage you need to:

```
const fruit = localStorage.getItem("fruit");
console.log(fruit); //prints 'apple';
```

Local storage only stores strings so if you want to store other types of data you need to convert it to JSON before:

```
localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(["apple", "banana"]));
```

And to retrieve it you need to convert it from JSON:

```
const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
console.log(cart) //prints ['apple', 'banana']
```